# Engine Rattle-like sound and power loss

Tags: engine, noise, peugeot, peugeot-308

My Peugeot 308 2009 1.6 Petrol has just developed a funny sound in the engine, its like there is misfire or cold start and car is now lost power mainly when going uphill.  the sound is like its a diesel engine. The Fan also doesn't go off after engine is switched off until after about 4 minutes .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Any check engine codes?

Comment: Sounds like preignition.